Is there any database that contains experimental data for quantum computing?
I've been looking for more than two days for any database that contains experimental data about quantum computers, for example : algorithms / number of qubits / number of gates / error obtained ...
I need it to contain at least 10000 instances.
If anyone has an idea, please help

The google QEC experiment papers have associated data uploaded to Zenodo, and take way more than 10K shots:
Data for "Suppressing quantum errors by scaling a surface code logical qubit"
Data for "Quantum error correction below the surface code threshold"

As to algorithms, there are two resources that I would start with:

The Quantum Algorithm Zoo has a collated list of algorithms, going back to the 90's and earlier, explaining the respective complexity.  It presently cites about 498 different references.
The survey of end-to-end resources by Daizell et al., which gives estimates of the number of gates and qubits, etc., to implement many algorithms including those listed in the Zoo above.  There looks to be several more than 1000 references cited in the survey.

Otherwise your question is pretty broad. If you are looking for hardware that has actually implemented any of the above algorithms and the errors so-obtained, I would be happy if such a database exists but I doubt it is available in one easy-to-find place; for example, different quantum computers might want to run different algorithms for different tests, and the industry has been hunting around for the best way to benchmark devices for a while now. You might want to search keywords such as "quantum volume" and/or "linear cross-entropy benchmarking," as these are some commonly used benchmarks.
